# Multiple-step operation generated errors. Check each status value

Tags: mysql, delphi, ado

Need some help for this error message that appears on delphi 7
First, i will describe some script:
On mySQL procedure script:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE ActualStok()

NOT DETERMINISTIC
CONTAINS SQL
SQL SECURITY DEFINER
COMMENT ''

BEGIN

 SELECT B.KD_BRG, B.NAMA_BRG, B.UKURAN, B.SATUAN,
 (B.JUMLAH_BRG-(SELECT IFNULL(SUM(D.JUMLAH_PAKAI_BRG),0)
                    FROM DETAIL_PAKAI_BRG D
 WHERE (D.STATUS_AMBIL='0') AND (D.KD_BRG=B.KD_BRG) AND (D.UKURAN=B.UKURAN)
                                                    AND (D.SATUAN=B.SATUAN))),
 B.KETERANGAN_BRG
 FROM BARANG B;
END;
```

Then i check that procedure --> CALL ActualStok();
And it's work. mySQL show me the expected result, and fine. There is no error.

So on delphi program, i try to execute this script:

procedure TFrmPersediaan.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);

```
begin
   FrmDtm.ADOQBarang.Close;
   FrmDtm.ADOQBarang.SQL.Clear;
   FrmDtm.ADOQBarang.SQL.Add('CALL ActualStok()');
   FrmDtm.ADOQBarang.Open;
end;
```

Delphi shows me a error message "Multiple-step operation generated errors. Check each status value."

Please somebody to help me to solve this problem.
Thank you for any participant.

Comment: I'm sure this question was asked recently

Answer (score 2):

This might due to unsupported date values by ADO. In my case the error was caused by date value 01-01-0020 in my Oracle database, which isn't recognized by ADO.